# how can i call a angular.js function from c# in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, function

i want call a binddata() function of angular from code behind or C#. Is it possible or not in asp.net.

```
$scope.bindAllData = function () {
        $scope.getFundedRatio.investors = $scope.investors;
        $scope.getFundedRatio.taxRates = $scope.taxRateInfo;
        $scope.getFundedRatio.incomeAssets = $scope.incomeAssetInfo;
        $scope.getFundedRatio.futureSavings = $scope.futureSavingInfo;
        $scope.getFundedRatio.spendingGoals = $scope.spendingGoalsInfo;
        $scope.getFundedRatio.portfolioAssets = $scope.portfolioAssetsInfo;
        $scope.getFundedRatio.privateAssets = $scope.privateAssetInfo;
}
```

Comment: That's a weird requirement.

Comment: ..and the answer is NO. $scope is just to tie a controller and view, and hence such name *scope*. I am not a angular developer but logic says, it cannot be exposed beyond controller unless it is participating in inheritance. Accessing through C# is out-of-question.

Comment: thats weird, maybe you can send a request to the server and the server will response instructions. Back in angular side, process the response and decide what function to call then send a new response containing the result.

Comment: i am just like javascript function because we can call javascript function from serverside then why can't call angular function from server side.

Comment: who said you can call javascript in server side? i think you are referring to node.js. But this one is different

Comment: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(),"", "javascript:function_Name(); ", true);

Comment: You should understand that `RegisterStartupScript`, `RegisterClientScriptBlock` just register (in simple words, say render to output html) the javascript code which is then invoked by the browser. That is not at all equivalent to saying you are calling JS function from C#.

Answer (score 0):

You can call only JavaScript functions from C# codebehind which are available directly on window variable.
Since $scope is accessible only inside a controller it will not be accessible directly to window object. However you can create a selector element in your DOM - like give any element an id selector (The element should be in same scope for which you want to call the scope method.). Now you can get the scope of the element by using:
HTML Template: Create a dummy div with an id. This div should be present in same controller scope.

```
<div id='div1'></div>
```

You can access the scope of this element outside your controller javascript using:

```
var elementScope =    angular.element(document.getElementById('div1')).scope()
```

Now you will be able to access any scope method or property.

```
elementScope.bindAllData();
```

From C# codebehind you can directly call a javascript code by using:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"CallMyScopeFunction","angular.element(document.getElementById('div1')).scope().bindAllData()",true);
```

Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use webservices or wcf services to host the logic and consume them using http get method in controller

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you the following approach:
Try using the combination of SignalR and AngularJS. First of all, install SignalR Nuget-package.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
```

After that, create a Hub with a SignalR broadcast-message:

```
public class SampleHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string message)
    {
        // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(message);
    }
}
```

In any of your ASP.NET backend-methods, you can use the following snippet to notify your Angular-method:

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<SampleHub>();
context.Clients.All.broadcastMessage("BindAllData");
```

Insert this in your script-part of the frontend:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/libs/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/libs/jquery.signalR.min.js"></script>
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

On the client side, use the following code:

```
var sampleHub = jQuery.connection.sampleHub;
sampleHub.client.broadcastMessage = function (message) {
     Console.log(message); // Will output "BindAllData"
     // Your BindAllData-code here.
}; 
jQuery.connection.hub.start();
```

I hope this works for you.